# How can I find the name of the current SAVEPOINT in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, transactions

I have a trigger `ON UPDATE` on a table that calls a custom function. In the custom function, I want to insert into a log table the name of the current SAVEPOINT (the deepest unsaved one) along with the name of the table and the timestamp. I am currently hardcoding the name of the table (please let me know if there is a better way) but I cannot figure out how to get the name of the current SAVEPOINT.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, SQLite has no functions to get the current savepoint (or the current trigger's table).

However, if you have compiled SQLite into your application, you could use `sqliteInt.h`, and, from a variable `sqlite3 *db`, access the current savepoint's name as `db->pSavepoint->zName`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to determine current save point, without resorting to using sqlite3int.h and the sqlite3* db structure is to set up a compile time authorization callback (http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/set_authorizer.html) and then look for an action code (http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_alter_table.html) of SQLITE_SAVEPOINT.

The fourth parameter passed to the authorizer callback will be the name of a savepoint.  By storing this name in your structure - you will have access to the name of the *last* save point passed in during analysis/preparation of your sqlite3_stmt.